# How to get both check box values and radio button values in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, radio-button

My demo https://embed.plnkr.co/R4mdZr/

I am new to angular as I mentioned I want to get both checkbox true values and radio button values ..

There is a condition if ingredients minimum value is equal to one means it will show as radio or else checkbox .

How to get those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ng-model when you're dealing with inputs. I'm not sure what values you want in your model, but you would typically use the ng-value directive here to assign a certain property, or perhaps the whole object to your ng-model.

For example

```
ng-value="get_ing_n"
```

Would assign the complete object to your model when you select a radio.

```
ng-value="get_ing_n.ingredientName"
```

Would bind the ingredientname.

I [forked your plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2qHhz5?p=preview) to demonstrate this. Beware however that there are some ng-init's present to format the model. It is generally not considered a good practice to put this logic into the view, so it's best to just use this as a reference.

If you want to apply some additional logic when selecting a checkbox/radio button, you can use the ng-change directive where you can call a function on your controller on model changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... OK this is an accepted answer if I want to pass the topics like Size and selected values and then Topping and there selected values means how to achieve that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you would set ng-value="get_ing_n" and ng-change="updateIngredient(get_ingredientTypeName_values.ingredientTypeName, selected_ingrediants[key])" the second parameter being your ng-model. Inside you controller you can access the properties on the object just as you normally would in js.

Comment: Exactly... Thanks a lot... A small help too how to remove when a checkbox got unselected ?

Comment: hi is there any way to get the title to push to array ?

Comment: What title? I see no title property in the json.

Comment: `"productName":"Pizza"` at the top

Comment: is that possible to get the value ?

Comment: Sure, just add get_ing_value.productName as a parameter https://plnkr.co/edit/k2Dnm9?p=preview

Comment: thank you but i want to push only one time not multiple times